# Vimscript - Mapping for commenting visual blocks

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to create a mapping on Vim, that behaves like the following:

First of all I select a block of code or text using on Visual mode.
The I use this mapping to substitute the first column on each line for '#' effectively commenting each line.

Up until now I have the following:

```
vnoremap <Leader>c :normal! :s/^/#/<cr>
```

But for some reason it is not working. Nothing happens when I hit `<Leader>c` on a block of text. On the other hand, if I have:

```
vnoremap <Leader>c :normal! s/^/#/<cr>
```

it will for example subsitute:

```
The grey fox.
```

For

```
/^/#/he grey fox.
```

Any idea on how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you using the normal command? It's supposed to be used to type keystrokes as if you were in normal mode

Comment: @Axnyff With the vnoremap <Leader>c :visual! s/^/#/<cr> line I get 'No range allowed' error.

Comment: Why the normal command? What about vnoremap <Leader>c :s/^/#/<cr>, it still has problem with the highlighting but it's already better

Comment: It already behaves better, but still has the highlighting problem. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you use the normal command for the right purpose it should work better:

vnoremap <Leader>c :normal I#<cr>
This will not be the first column though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:normal` is an Ex command that allows to execute *normal mode* commands (from a custom command or function, or command-line mode in general). Your keys start off with `:`, so immediately switch from normal (or here: visual) mode to command-line mode. That doesn't make sense. Just define the mapping like this:

```
vnoremap <Leader>c :s/^/#/<cr>
```

The `:` will automatically insert `'<,'>` for you, and that's what you want here (to operate on all selected lines). You can also define a related normal-mode mapping that works on the current (or `[count]`) lines:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :s/^/#/<cr>
```

If the highlighting disturbs you, append the `:nohlsearch` command:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :s/^/#/<bar>nohlsearch<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
vnoremap <leader>c :s/^/#/<cr>
```

The substitution command will get the range, `'<,'>`, automatically when in visual mode.

Note: you probably want to use `xnoremap` instead of `vnoremap`.

#### There is a better way

Commenting is a common problem, deceptively tricky, and already solved by [many plugins](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). I prefer to stand on the shoulder's of giants and use a plugin. I personally use  [commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm actually practicing with vimscript, so my goal is to create a simple commenting plugin by myself.

Comment: You probably want to use `:keeppatterns` with `:substitute` as without it `:s` will mutate the search register, `"/`. This would be a surprising side-effect. See `:h "/` and `:h :keeppatterns`.